# Future cancel method documentation

Tags: java, concurrency, future, java.util.concurrent

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html `isDone` returns `true` if `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` was called.

> After this method returns, subsequent calls to isDone() will always return true.

However, it is possible that task is running and `mayInterruptIfRunning` is set to `false`. So, what should return `isDone()` right after that call? `true` because of cancel (which is wrong)?

Also, it's not clear whether `cancel(boolean)` method returns `false`.

P. S. I'm implementing some simple thread pool, so I'm inheriting from `Future`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. After `cancel(...)`, `isDone()` should always be `true`. It doesn't matter what `cancel(...)` returned.
2. If `cancel(...)` returns `true` it means this future is now cancelled and `isCancelled()==true`
3. If `cancel(...)` returns `false` it means that the completion was not due to this call to `cancel()`
4. `cancel(false)` means that the `cancel` method should not attempt to cancel the task that is trying to complete the future (the meaning of "task" depending on the `Future`'s implementation), the task will keep running but the future is cancelled (isDone()==true).
5. `cancel(true)` means that there should be an attempt to cancel the running task, regardless if the attempt is successful or not the future will be cancelled (isDone()==true).

Remember that this is a contract, it has to be enforced by the `Future`'s implementation.

**Edit:** `isDone()` is always true after `cancel()`

Here's a test to experiment with some of the scenarios:

```
@Test
public void test() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    CompletableFuture c1 = new CompletableFuture();
    CompletableFuture c2 = new CompletableFuture();
    Future<String> future = threadExecutor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            c1.complete(null);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            c2.complete("normal");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            c2.complete("interrupted");
        }
        return "aaa";
    });
    c1.join(); // waits for the task start
    // future.get(); // awaits the completion
    System.out.println("cancel:     " + future.cancel(true));
    //System.out.println("cancel:     " + future.cancel(false));
    System.out.println("isDone:     " + future.isDone());
    System.out.println("isCanceled: " + future.isCancelled());
    System.out.println("task:       " + c2.join());
}
```